# Unable to install dependencies in IHP blog demo project

Tags: haskell, nix, ihp

I'm new to IHP so I'm following the [getting started guide](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/your-first-project.html).

I'm now stuck in the [last part of Section 5 (extending with markdown)](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/your-first-project.html#markdown).

When explaining how to install the required package, this are the instructions:

---

#### Adding a Markdown Library

To deal with Markdown, instead of implementing a custom Markdown parser, let’s just use an existing package. There’s the excellent [mmark](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmark) package we can use.

To install this package, open the `default.nix` file and append `mmark` to the `haskellDeps` list. The file will now look like this:

```hs
let
    ihp = builtins.fetchGit {
        url = "https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp.git";
        ref = "refs/tags/v0.10.0";
    };
    haskellEnv = import "${ihp}/NixSupport/default.nix" {
        ihp = ihp;
        haskellDeps = p: with p; [
            cabal-install
            base
            wai
            text
            hlint
            p.ihp
            mmark # <--------- OUR NEW PACKAGE ADDED HERE
        ];
        otherDeps = p: with p; [
            # Native dependencies, e.g. imagemagick
        ];
        projectPath = ./.;
    };
in
    haskellEnv
```

Stop the development server by pressing CTRL+C. Then update the local development environment by running `make -B .envrc`. This will download and install the mmark package. Now restart the development server by typing `./start` again.

---

Here I have a couple of problems.

Firstly, my `default.nix` looks completely different, like this:

```hs
# For backwards compatibility using flake.nix
(import
    (
        fetchTarball {
            url = "https://github.com/edolstra/flake-compat/archive/12c64ca55c1014cdc1b16ed5a804aa8576601ff2.tar.gz";
            sha256 = "0jm6nzb83wa6ai17ly9fzpqc40wg1viib8klq8lby54agpl213w5";
        }
    )
{ src = ./.; }).defaultNix
```

Did I miss some initial configuration? Or is it supposed to look like that and I have to manually add all of that?

Secondly, when I try to run the command `make -B .envrc` I get the following error:

```bash
$ make -B .envrc
echo "This command is deprecated. Please use 'devenv up' instead"
This command is deprecated. Please use 'devenv up' instead
```

But I don't know how to run `devenv up`. I tried a couple of options I though could work like running it through the `nix-shell` but same error was raised.

Comment: there is a comment `For backwards compatibility using flake.nix`. Is there any `flake.nix` file? maybe you have to add your dependency there,,, I don't know nix btw

Comment: That was a part of the issue, thank you very much!
The other part was that I didn't have `devenv` installed so I was unable to run that command. I started over installing `cachix` and `devenv` prior to creating the project with `ihp-new blog` and is working fine for now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

#### Solved

There were two problems:

First, as Ismor suggested in the first comment, I had to add the dependencies inside the `flake.nix` file.

And second, I didn't have `devenv` installed so I was unable to run that command. I started over installing `cachix` (recommended before installing `devenv`) and `devenv` prior to creating the project with `ihp-new blog`. Then I was able to run `devenv up`, packages got installed and everything is working fine now.

I'm using the latest IHP version, so maybe the [IHP Guide](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/index.html) is a bit outdated.

Comment: you can contribute by opening an issue in the github repo pointing out these two problems! :)

Comment: IHP is in the middle of updating their boilerplate in anticipation of IHP v1.1.0 which is slated for release soon. The Getting Started guide is unfortunately a bit out of date as a result, as you conjectured.